# Python for Google App Engine: 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine

Hello when testing out the GET and POST methods of I am continually getting 405 Method Not Allowed The method POST is not allowed for this resource. The plan is for users to post both name and nickname and use ajax to save and then display the inputs.

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

mainPage = """
   <html>
<head>
    <title>Pokemon List</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js.js"></script>

</head>


<body>

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
        <h1>Pokemon App</h1>
 <div data-role="page" id="menu" class="info">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h3>Menu</h3>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" id="backbutton" data-theme="c" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="menuList">
            <ul id="actions2" data-role="listview" >

                <li><a href="#input" data-transition="none">Input Data</a></li>
                <li><a href="#data" data-transition="none">Check Data</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

<div data-role="page" id="input" class="info">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
        <h1>Post data</h1>
        <a href="#input" data-role="button" data-rel="back"  id="backbutton2" data-theme="c" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
    </div>
  <title>Name and Message</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Input Name</h2>
        <form method='post'>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type='text' id="name" name="name" size="40" value="{{user}}"/><br/>
        <label for="nickname">Nickname</label>
        <textarea id="nickname" name="nickname" rows="6" cols="50"></textarea><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Button" />
    </form><br/>

    <table>
            {% for nickname in messages %}
                {{ nickname.asTableRow }}
            {% endfor %}
        </table>



    <div data-role="namelist" >
        <ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="delete" data-split-theme="a" data-inset="true" class="list"  id="list">


        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
   </div>


        </body>
</html>

"""

class Message(db.Model):
    # This one has 3 properties...


    user = db.StringProperty()
    name = db.StringProperty()
    nickname = db.StringProperty()
    timestamp = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)


    def asString(self):
        return "%s user name: %s the nickname %s " %(self.user, self.name, self.nickname)

    def asJSONString(self):
        return '{"name": "%s", "nickname": "%s"}' % (self.user, self.name, self.nickname)


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        usr = self.request.get('user')
        nme = self.request.get('name')
        nnme = self.request.get('nickname')
       # self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
        self.response.out.write(mainPage)

        if len(usr) > 0 and len(nnme) > 0:
            newmsg = Message(user=usr,name=nme,nickname=nnme)
            newmsg.put()
        #else:
            #self.response.out.write('Error in input')

def getJSONMessages(callback):
        messages = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Message ORDER BY timestamp")
        strlist = ""
        for message in messages:
            if len(strlist)>0:
                strlist += ',' + message.asJSONString()
            else:
                strlist = message.asJSONString()
        if callback =='':
            return '[' + strlist + ']'
        else:
            return callback+ '([' + strlist +']);'

class JSONInterface(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        usr =self.request.get('usr')
        nnme =self.request.get('nnme')

        callback = self.request.get('callback')
        if len(usr) > 0 and len(nnme) >0:
            newmsg = Message(name=usr, nickname=nnme)
            newmsg.put()
        if len(usr)>0:
            self.response.out.write(getJSONMessages(callback))
        else:
            self.response.out.write("something didnt work")

    def get(self):
        callback = self.request.get('callback')
        self.response.out.write(getJSONMessages(callback))


app= webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                                      ('/json', JSONInterface)], debug=True)



def main():
    run_wsgi_app(app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The app successfully deploys to Google App Engine. I have checked the logs in App Engine but have not found errors. Can someone tell if it is a problem to do with my python code. I am currently working on some JSON with javascript, could that be required in order to get the GET, POST methods to work?
Thanks for the time and help.

Update

If I change my MainPage request handler to post, I still get the 405 method error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `form` your method is `post` but in the `MainHandler`,your method is `get`, maybe that's why you see `405 method not allowed`

Comment: I tried changing the form to get. Which allows the submit button to used without errors but when trying to use post all with the Postman Plugin I still get the 405 error. The intention of this app is to post with that form with the submit button. Thanks for the advice, I will look into this problem further.